# converting coordinates from unusual DMS format to decimal

Tags: r, coordinates

So I've been shared a dataset with what to me is an unusual format for degree min second data.
In their own words:

```
    The coordinates provided are longitude and latitude in degrees minutes and seconds.
    So for example, coordinates recorded in the spreadsheet as 
    X_Long: -10.0135 Y_Lat:  53.5726, can be taken as Longitude: 10º 01'35" W, 
    Latitude: 53º 57'26" N using standard notation.
```

I need to get this into decimal. Any quick way to do this ?

Edit:

in trying to solve this I made a following code:

```
    # Fake data
    X_Long <- as.numeric(c(-2.4564, -1.0134, -8.01))

    long.temp <- abs(X_Long - trunc(X_Long))
    long.min <- trunc(long.temp*100)
    long.sec <- trunc(as.integer((long.temp*100 - long.min)*100))
```

Its giving me weird rounding errors:

```
    > X_Long
    [1] -2.4564 -1.0134 -8.0100
    > long.temp
    [1] 0.4564 0.0134 0.0100
    > long.min
    [1] 45  1  0
    > long.sec
    [1] 63 34 99
```

This seems to be coming from the trunc function - compare results here

```
    > long.temp*100
    [1] 45.64  1.34  1.00
    > trunc(long.temp*100)
    [1] 45  1  0
```

Anyone know why this is happening ?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404596/)

Comment: I have - it doesn't help me. This format doens't have helpful markers between minutes and seconds. I'm having a hard time teasing them apart. I had some code I thought would work but I found a bug - will edit main question

Comment: This is FAQ 7.31 format(abs(-8.01 - trunc(-8.01))*100, digits = 16)

Comment: Sorry i don't follow you - what FAQ- do you have a link ?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
fun <- function(x, ...) {
   ## determine sign, this complicates the whole thing 
   sgn <- grepl("^-", x)
   ## split on the "." separator
   parts <- strsplit(x, "\\.")
   ## extract the minute/seconds digits, convert to numeric, scale, and sign
   ifelse(sgn, -1, 1) * sapply(parts, function(x)   sum(abs(as.numeric(c(x[1L], substr(x[2L], 1, 2), substr(x[2L], 3, 5))) / c(1, 60, 3600))))
}
```

The code would be a lot neater without having to find the sign up front and apply it to the sum. (Well I can't see a neater way).

```
fun("-10.0135")
[1]  -10.02639

fun("53.5726")
[1] 53.95722
```

It's vectorized:

```
fun(c("-10.0135", "53.5726", "-35.0020"))
[1] -10.02639  53.95722 -35.00556
```

You probably want checks for sensible inputs, treating lon/lat separately etc.

Check round-tripping (here we have to separate for lon/lat)

```
  require(sp)
  dd2dms(fun("-10.0135"))
  [1] 10d1'35"W

  dd2dms(fun(c("53.5726", "-35.0020")), NS = TRUE)
  [1] 53d57'26"N 35d0'20"S
```

Comment: thx  but my fake data above breaks it

        fun(as.character(X_Long))
        [1] -2.767778 -1.026111        NA

Comment: Well if you are coercing numeric to character you'll need to get the formatting right, as it stands with your edit the question is kind of open-ended now.

Comment: Yeah I guess there are two questions now - but I just want anything that will work. The edit was my own attempt at being clever but I guess it didn't work :( I can probably fix the formatting inside excel - i.e. just fix it to show 4 decimals always and export as csv

Comment: Well it depends on the need, my function can be changed to be more flexible, but if you have numeric input there are many more cases to catch. It should not be numeric ever if the format is taken seriously, perhaps Excel is the main problem.

Comment: Ha this insane format is the main problem :) Actually just talking to you it occurs to me I could do all this conversion in excel - not ideal but I'd have it done by now. I'm still puzzled by the weird rounding errors I had with the trunc function above